# How to print only the kafka record value and not all of the other data?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

So I'm new to kafka, and i've been following some tutorials and searching on the internet and I have managed to set a producer and consumer script in Java. But instead of just printing the message (value), I get the following result in the eclipse console:

```java
ConsumerRecord(topic = MyTopic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 131, CreateTime = 1579178094212, serialized key size = 10, serialized value size = 31, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = Simple Key, value = Custom test message)
```

Instead, If i run the consumer in the windows console, i get only the value, meaning i get "Custom test message".

How can I select and print only the "value" property from the kafka consumer record on the eclipse console? Or any other property for that matter.

**EDIT**:

For the person who asked how I printed all that data, this is the code in my consumer script:

```java
    package com.okta.javakafka.kafkajava;

    import java.util.Arrays;

    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;

    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;



    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    public class SimpleConsumer {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
            ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
            root.setLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
            props.put("group.id","test");
            props.put("enable.auto.commit","true");
            props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms","1000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put("key.deserializer",Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"));
            props.put("value.deserializer", Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"));

            KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(props);
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("MyTopic"));

            try {
                while(true) {
                    ConsumerRecords<String,String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
                    for(ConsumerRecord<String,String> record : records)
                    System.out.println(record.toString());

                }

            }finally {
                consumer.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you print that data at all? What code does that for you, please?

Comment: `ConsumerRecord.value()` will give you that `https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html#value--`

Comment: @Deadpool Thank you. That did the trick

Comment: @ArtemBilan Added the original code, hope it helps

Comment: Note: You duplicated `group.id` and `ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG`, and `Class.forName` isn't necessary

Answer (score 3):

You do `System.out.println(record.toString());`. 
This is definitely about the whole `ConsumerRecord`.

To print only the value you need to do this:

```
System.out.println(record.value());
```